# Need help making a macro that deletes cells with more than 7 characters

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel and I'm having a hard time trying to find a macro to delete a row if a cell contains more than 7 characters. I know I'm supposed to use =len(a1) to get the length, but the language is really archaic to me.

If someone can make me the macro, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: over which range? have you tried anything? what did you already build?

Comment: are you only looking in a specific column? or any column?

Comment: I only have one column, over the range of everythin (or say 100k).

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub test2()
    Dim last As Long, i As Long
    'make sure it works with any sheet size
    last = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'loop bottom to top !
    For i = last To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Cells(i, 1)) > 7 Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the second code. You should just delete the first as the second is *the* way to go by far. Proper use of rows.count, long instead of integer...it's flawless.

Comment: ok. Will do. I *wanted* to do it with a For Each, but you can't make it backwards, hence the need for additional passes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this assuming the data is in column A:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim r As Integer

    Let r = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do Until r = 0
        If Len(Cells(r, 1)) > 7 Then Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Let r = r - 1
    Loop
    Let r = Empty
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I saw it do something as my cells shifted up, but there's still just as many 7+ character words as before.

Comment: Can you confirm that the words are in column A and are not derived by formulas?  Also you could try commenting out the Screen updating rows of the macro (with a ' at the start of the row)

Comment: @tony, r is an Integer, so you don't need the word Let or the =Empty statement. (You can use Let though, just optional).

Comment: Thank you Lance - I know the Let is optional but didn't realise that =Empty is not necessary for integer items.

Comment: I would suggest you use Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlUp).Row instead. Hard coding the row count is not good practice since it will vary from versions of Excel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I thought I would give you another solution. I tried it and it works.

```
Sub DeleteAbove7()

    Dim b1 As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim v1 As Variant

    v1 = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" _
         & Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2)

    b1 = False
    For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
        If Len(v1(i)) > 7 Then
            If b1 Then
                Set r1 = Union(r1, Cells(i, 1))
            Else
                Set r1 = Cells(i, 1)
                b1 = True
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    r1.EntireRow.Delete

    'ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & UBound(v1)) = Application.Transpose(v1)

    Set r1 = Nothing
    Set v1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to worry about setting r1 and v1 to nothing. At the end of the sub all local variables are released (garbage collected).

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. For some reason I thought you always had to do it. I don't remember where I learned it from, maybe Professional Excel Development. In there he just says it's good practice to explicitly terminate objects, but he doesn't say it's actually necessary. The example he used was a global variable. Anyways, TMI, thanks for the tip!